# Why do we have surface charges on a polymer sheet immerged in water ?

Tags: electrochemistry, polymers, surface-chemistry, electricity

I am working with a conductive polymer sheet where I have dropped off a drop of water (with ions). I have plugged the polymer with a conductive wire and an other wire is on the drop. With a voltmeter I measure a voltage (open circuit) between these two points the drop and the polymer (around 300 mV)
And when I use a resistor in my circuit, I can measure an intensity. So What happens on my polymer ? Where come from the electrons crossing my resistor ?

[image]

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/47811/where-does-the-charge-on-an-electrode-responsible-for-the-formation-of-a-double/47812#47812